# Cannot resolve original image by using IFFT in python, only black

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I have spatial frequency fourier transforms of different apertures (gratings etc) and I'm trying to resolve the aperture by performing an IFFT from `scipy`. However, I just keep getting a black screen. Where am I going wrong?

I can perform a FFT on the black IFFT and still get the original image back, though. In the attached image is also a FFT and then IFFT of a two different apertures, the top row is where my issue is.

```
import numpy as np
import imageio.v3 as iio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from scipy.fft import ifft2, fft2, ifftshift, fftshift

path = r'C:\\Users\\Plowa\\Exercism\\python\\fourier optics RLI'
pixelset = iio.imread(os.path.join(path, 'E fourier_0.bmp'))
pixelset2 = iio.imread(os.path.join(path, 'E in transform plane_0.bmp'))
pixelset = pixelset[:,:,0]
pixelset2 = pixelset2[:,:,0]

ft_pixels_2 = fftshift(fft2(pixelset2))
ift_pixels_2 = ifft2(ifftshift(ft_pixels_2))
ift_pixels = ifft2(ifftshift(fftshift(pixelset), axes=(0,1)))
pixels = fft2(fftshift(ift_pixels))

x = np.arange(-500, 501, 1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
grating = 10*(np.exp(-((X-100)/10)**2) + np.exp(-((X+100)/10)**2))
ft_grating = fftshift(fft2(ifftshift(grating)))
ift_grating = ifftshift(ifft2(fftshift(ft_grating)))

f, ((ax2, ax1, ax6), (ax3, ax4, ax5), (ax7, ax8, ax9)) = plt.subplots(3, 3)
inv_fourier_image = ax1.imshow(abs(ift_pixels), cmap ='gray')
image = ax2.imshow(pixelset, cmap='gray')
ax3.imshow(grating, cmap='gray')
ax4.imshow(abs(ft_grating), cmap='gray')
ax5.imshow(abs(ift_grating), cmap='gray')
ax6.imshow(abs(pixels), cmap='gray')
ax4.set_xlim(450,550)
ax4.set_ylim(520,480)
ax7.imshow(pixelset2, cmap='gray')
ax8.imshow(20*np.log(abs(ft_pixels_2)), cmap='gray')
ax9.imshow(abs(ift_pixels_2), cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Resulting image:
[image]

I've tried searching for similar problems, but can't find any.

Comment: Play with the contrast when displaying. `imshow` has `vmin` and `vmax` parameters that you can use to do so. Lower the max value until you see your data (the min value should probably just be 0).

Comment: All that `ifftshift`ing before transformations is irrelevant if you only look at the magnitude of the transformed image. Otherwise you’d have to find the exact center of the interference pattern, and move that to the top-left of the image, because they are not at all properly centered.

Comment: Side note: `((ax2, ax1, ax6), (ax3, ax4, ax5)...` is very bad practice of assigning variable names. Either sort those names or use `fig, axes = plt.subplots(...)`  (then use it this way: `axes[row_idx, col_idx]`